# installation error package/DESCRIPTION after upgrading R and R studio

Tags: r, dplyr

Recently I updated R and R studio

R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt) -- "Eye Holes"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

RStudio 2023.09.1+494 "Desert Sunflower" Release (cd7011dce393115d3a7c3db799dda4b1c7e88711, 2023-10-16) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

While installing a package, for e.g. `dplyr`, I get the following error

```
Warning in install.packages :
 error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'fansi/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Similarly, if I try to install any other package

```
install.packages("mime")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/mime_0.12.zip'
Content type 'text/html' length 9120 bytes
downloaded 9120 bytes

Warning in install.packages :
error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
 cannot open compressed file 'mime/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Would anyone be able to advise what is causing this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762712/r-error-in-install-packages-cannot-open-the-connection

Comment: I think "downloaded 9120 bytes" is a clue; according to the "https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/" webpage the mime package is 40Kb, so maybe an issue with your internet connection / firewall / ssl package? Have you tried reinstalling R / RStudio?

Comment: Thanks. When I try to manually download the mime zip, it gets blocked by my firewall.